# What's the difference between _init vs _start?

Tags: dynamic-linking, elf

_start runs first, even though _init is pointed to by the DT_INIT dynamic entry as the initialization function.
Could someone explain to me the purpose of DT_INIT if it seems to serve no purpose as the _start symbols is always the entry point.

Comment: Start by reading `man ld.so readelf`.

Comment: I have extensively been reading about ELF format and experimenting in gdb. I found using gdb that ld.so starts at a different location than it's entry point and ld.so contains no _init so I am confused.